# Different ways of saying dates in US English

Tags: american-english, formality

This question is about the stylistic differences between certain expressions in **American English**.

When one has to say a date out loud, there are 4 possibilities in US English.

1. "Month + ordinal", e.g., "April tenth"
2. "Month + cardinal", e.g., "April ten"
3. "Month + the + ordinal", e.g., "April the tenth"
4. "The+ cardinal + month + ordinal", e.g., "the tenth of April"

I think that the most common in everyday usage is the first one, followed by the second (however, I think the second method is not used with small number, like in "March one" or "October two"; can anyone confirm it?). I believe that the first format is perfectly fine for all occasions, while the second might be a little informal. What about the last two? Are they commonly used in the US? Do they sound more formal?

Answer (score -1):

There are all of these variants exist. But the form "April the tenth" is the most common, as for me. "April tenth" - people say so, but I hear it rarely. "The tenth of April" - a formal variant. "April ten" - I'd say that it's not commonly used.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to the ELU. On this site, more thorough answers are encouraged. See [tour](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour). It would be good to provide references for the information your are giving.

Comment: Hello, and thank you. It's just examples from my everyday life that I can share. I mostly use American English for work, so I decided to answer here.

Comment: I would say 1 and 4 are commonly heard, while 3 is rare and 2 is almost never used. Ngram tends to support this. Though 2 is probably more common in written English.

Comment: I am hearing 2 more often these days on radio and TV (in Australia).